# How to get the bitmap width and height inside Custom ImageView after inserting

Tags: android, imageview

Can somebody help me with getting the width of the bitmap after it was place inside a custom imageview.

This is my current code but this code only get the width of the imageview.

```
// is place in the Activity
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
 int bW = myImageV.getWidth();
 int bH = myImageV.getHeight();
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapFactory.Options will help you to get width and height of bitmap before it loaded in to your custom ImageView . try this..

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

After adding bitmap to your custom Image view ,If you want to calculate your bitmap width and height ,you should use Ract and canvas like this ,In a simple words Ract is basically draw bound area of your bitmap using canvas.

```
Drawable drawable = myImageView.getDrawable();
//you should call after the bitmap drawn
Rect bounds = drawable.getBounds();
int width = bounds.width();
int height = bounds.height();

Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.set(myImageView.getImageMatrix());
float[] values = new float[9];
m.getValues(values);
int bitmapWidth = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(); //your bitmap's width
int bitmapHeight = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]*drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(); //your the bitmap's height
```

Comment: Hi @Radhe. We're do I put your code.? Is it after myImageV.setImageDrawable(drawable1);? I want the width as height of the bitmap inside custom imageview. Thanks

Comment: you want to calculate width and height before set up bitmap inside image view ? refer this http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap

Comment: No. Sorry for misunderstanding. I want to get width and height of the bitmap after it was displayed on the custom imageview sir.

Comment: Hi @Radhe. You should read my updated question. I am looking for way to get the w and Height of the bitmap after being put to custom ImageView not before putting it on. This helps me float width = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*backgroundImage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth(); I get it from matrix

Comment: Hi @Radhe, I edited your answer. drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() alone and drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() will not get the right width. Because my custom imageview is set to scaletype = fitCenter. So it might scale. I don't need the Rect bounds.

Comment: set your scaletype = fitCenter. to FIT_XY  and let me know , may be I'm not getting you correctly why you want your bitmap size after set it inside imageview .any purpose ?

Comment: I have two ImageView inside a Relativelayout. The first layer which is at the back (Custom ImageView which was set to scaletype = fitCenter) is for displaying any picture. And the 2nd Custom ImageView at the front is a Layered Type which display many bitmap that you can drag, rotate, scale. This two View is center Vertically and H. So I want the front imageView to adjust to the actual size of the bitmap at the back(first Custom ImageView) not the ImageView itself.